# x bins with capacity y, x*y items, maximize total score where each (item, bin) pair has an associated score

Tags: algorithm, max, constraints

```
x bins, each with capacity y
x*y items
each (item, bin) pair has an associated score
```

Is there a standard algorithm for maximizing the total score given the criteria above?

Answer (score 0):

It is just variation to knapsack problem, it is very common one : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

---

In knapsack problem, the complexity is `O(2^n)`, this would have `O(k^n)`, where `k` is number of bins.

---

The solution : For knapsack problem, you can write every possibility as number with 0 and 1, where 0 means the item in that position is not in bag, 1 means it is in bag.

For this problem, it is similar, but 0 and 1 is not enough, you have to know in which bag the item is, therefore you have to remember position of bag.

For example if you have 6 items, you can write it as this number (or array) :

```
005110
```

Which can mean that first and second item is not in any bag, third is in 5th bag, next is in first bag, next is in first bag, next is not in any bag.

---

The engineering recommended process : Create your own fully working knapsack problem, then rewrite it to this problem. (as knapsack problem is basically this one with only one bin)

Comment: I have just started looking at this, but in each knapsack-type problem I have seen so far each item has a set, single value (or profit, etc). In the situation above an item does not have a single value; rather, its value is dependent on which bin it is in.

Comment: @CraigBurgler - yes, thats why it is "variation" to knapsack problem, not knapsack problem. However solution remains the same, the only change is, that instead of remember if item is in bag or not, you remember if item is in bag and in which one or he is not in anyone. Based on that, you can easily count the total score for each possibility.